# Cut the tree ,most of test cases evaluating incorrect

Tags: algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

The problem as stated on the site is

Atul is into graph theory, and he is learning about trees nowadays. He observed that the removal of an edge from a given tree T will result in the formation of two separate trees, T1 and T2.

Each vertex of the tree T is assigned a positive integer. Your task is to remove an edge, such that the Tree_diff of the resultant trees is minimized. Tree_diff is defined as the following:

F(T) = Sum of numbers written on each vertex of a tree T

Tree_diff(T) = abs(F(T1) - F(T2))

Input Format 
The first line will contain an integer N, i.e. the number of vertices in the tree.
The next line will contain N integers separated by a single space, i.e. the values assigned to each of the vertices (where the first one is the root of the tree).
The next N−1 lines contain a pair of integers each, separated by a single space, that denote the edges of the tree.
In the above input, the vertices are numbered from 1 to N.

Output Format 
A single line containing the minimum value of Tree_diff.

```
Constraints 
3≤N≤10^5 
1≤ number written on each vertex ≤1001
```

Here is [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-tree) to the problem

So what I did is using a recursive dfs calculated the sum of wts of all subtrees including the largest tree as well which is = total sum of vertex values.

Now when we remove an edge say u-v, u is parent, the difference can simply be calculated as:

```
abs(w[tree[0][u]-1]-(tot-w[tree[0][u]-1]))
```

where

```
tree[0][u]=v
tot=total sum of all vertices weights.
w[tree[0][u]-1] = sum of wts of all vertices of subtree rooted at vertex v
F(T1)=(tot-w[tree[0][u]-1])
F(T2)=(w[tree[0][u]-1])
```

if instead of left child, its the right child we will have

```
tree[1][u]-1]
```

instead of

```
tree[0][u]-1]
```

It does not matter whether the first row consist left child in tree[][] array or second row cause the structure may change but the answer will remain same.

Here is my java code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Dfs {
    static int n;
    static int [][]tree = new int[2][100000];
    static long []wt=new long[100000];
    static long []w=new long[100000];
    static int []con=new int[100000];
    static int root=0;
    static long min=Long.MAX_VALUE;
    static long tot=0;
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
    {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String []sa;int i,u,v;
        n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        sa=br.readLine().split(" ");i=0;
        for(String s:sa)
         wt[i++]=Long.parseLong(s);
        for(i=0;i<n-1;++i)
        {
            sa=br.readLine().split(" ");
            u=Integer.parseInt(sa[0]);
            v=Integer.parseInt(sa[1]);

            if(i==0)
            {
                tree[0][u-1]=v;
                root=u;
            }    
            else
            {
                if(con[u-1]==-1)
                {
                    if(tree[0][u-1]==0)
                      tree[0][u-1]=v;
                    else tree[1][u-1]=v;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(tree[0][v-1]==0)
                      tree[0][v-1]=u;
                    else tree[1][v-1]=u;
                }    
            }    
            con[u-1]=-1;
            con[v-1]=-1;
        }
        tot=dfs(root);
        w[root-1]=tot;        
        for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
            if(tree[0][i]!=0)
            {
                if(min>Math.abs(w[tree[0][i]-1]-(tot-w[tree[0][i]-1])))
                    min=Math.abs(w[tree[0][i]-1]-(tot-w[tree[0][i]-1]));
            }
            if(tree[1][i]!=0)
            {
                if(Math.abs(w[tree[1][i]-1]-(tot-w[tree[1][i]-1]))<min)
                    min=Math.abs(w[tree[1][i]-1]-(tot-w[tree[1][i]-1]));
            }
        } 
        System.out.println(min);
    }
    static long dfs(int v)
    {        
        long s1=0,s2=0;
        if(tree[0][v-1]!=0)
        {s1=dfs(tree[0][v-1]);w[tree[0][v-1]-1]=s1;}        
        if(tree[1][v-1]!=0)
        {s2=dfs(tree[1][v-1]);w[tree[1][v-1]-1]=s2;}
        return wt[v-1]+s1+s2;
    }    
}
```

The problem is that it is giving wrong answer for most of the test cases.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to assume that the tree is binary. Is this really a given?

Comment: You can also check this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/38311904/2034733](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38311904/2034733)

Answer (score 1):

I see three aspects that could make your code fail a test:

1. Your code assumes that the tree is a binary tree. I am not sure you can assume this, as it is nowhere mentioned in the challenge. So that would already put your data structure into question, as you reserve *tree[0]* for leftward branches and *tree[1]* for rightward branches. Instead, you should probably build your tree from the bottom up, in a `parent[i] = j` kind of structure.
2. Secondly, your code defines the root vertex as being the one mentioned as the first vertex of the first edge. But this seems unnecessary and could even be wrong: it says concerning the vertices that *"the first one is the root"*, so that just means you should set `root=1` in all cases. Whether or not the first listed edge has the root as the left most vertex is not specified.
3. Also, your code assumes that the sequence of edges is given in such an order that at least one of its vertices is already part of the tree you are building, but that is maybe not guaranteed. The edges could be listed in any order, at least the challenge does not make any promises in that respect. When this happens, your code assumes that the first of the two vertices (*u*) is the child of the second(*v*), but it might well be that it should be in the other direction. To solve this, you would need to go through the list of edges in a recursive way, making sure to only add edges when you are sure how they are directed.

Mainly because of point 1, your algorithm would need quite some rework.